# Move product data tabs up (Woocommerce)

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have problem with move product data tabs up. First I use function to remove tabs from current location. I use standard:

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_output_product_data_tabs', 10  );
```

but it does not remove tabs. I was able to remove tabs only by code:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_tabs', 'woo_remove_product_tabs', 98 );

function woo_remove_product_tabs( $tabs ) {

  unset( $tabs['description'] );        // Remove the description tab
  unset( $tabs['reviews'] );            // Remove the reviews tab
  // unset( $tabs['additional_information'] );      // Remove the additional information tab

  return $tabs;

}
```

But if I use this code, I can't "add_action" with product tabs in other place.

To add tabs I use:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_output_product_data_tabs', 33 );
```

Now tabs appear at the end of column. I want to move it up before grouped product thumbnails. How to do it?

Comment: which theme are you use?

Comment: you mean last two tabs??

Comment: Opis produktu tab in this page

Comment: single product description page code?

Comment: Yes, I mean last two tabs - "Opis produktu" and "Oceny" to move up before product thumbnails

Comment: @pat, I tried the remove and add actions, and they're working fine...

Comment: @Reigel maybe it depends of theme. I use remove and add actions on other parts of product-content and it works. I have only problem to remove this tabs and add it higher.

Comment: you are right @pat its theme setting,You can find this hook in function.php of your theme.this theme is free or paid??

Comment: @VasimVanzara yes, it's paid theme. I look into functions.php and I find code: `code
// Remove WooCommerce Tabs Action
remove_action('woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_output_product_data_tabs'); `
if I comment it tabs are visible also above the tab "Pokrewne produkty"

Comment: Have you got any ideas?

Comment: @VasimVanzara have you got idea?

Answer (score 0):

all of the hooks are just functions so you nedd created a new function and included the product description code:

```
function woocommerce_template_product_description() {
woocommerce_get_template( 'single-product/tabs/description.php' );
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_product_description', 20 );
```

Now call do action function in your single product file of your theme.

```
do_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary');
```

Comment: what? why need to create a new function?

Comment: hmm when I use this function product description show but without formatting and tabs